# How to implement CdkDrag globally that will have impact on all the MatDialogs throughout the application?

Tags: draggable, angular14, angular-cdk-drag-drop, mat-dialog

We are using Angular 14 in our project. We are having almost 100+ components. Most of the components are called by opening the Mat dialog box. Currently we are making all the Mat dialogs draggable. So we are using  'cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".mat-dialog-container" cdkDragHandle' in all the components. Is there a way to make the drag changes in one place like instead of adding the above in all the components, making the drag changes in one place that will reflect in all the Mat dialog boxes?.

Changes are working by adding cdkDrag. I need to make changes in one place instead of doing it in all the components.